# Сделать копию участка памяти по указателю?

Tags: c++, указатели, pcap

Доброго времени суток!
Проблема вот в чём: есть переменная pcap_t*, которая указывает на первый байт куска памяти, куда был помещен файл .pcap после открытия. Я хочу данный трафик обработать и установить на него фильтр, всё успешно. Только вот потом вернуться к изначальному трафику в программе нельзя, ведь на него установлен фильтр и вообще уже обработан loop'ом(функцию обработки скидывать не стал). Вопрос в том, как в функцию(см. readDnsPacket), где собственно этот фильтр устанавливается, закинуть копию трафика, а не оригинал. Необходимо это для того, чтобы далее в программе была возможность работать с оригиналом. 
PS: закрыть и открыть заново pcap не предлагать))) простите, что так муторно объясняю!
вот частичный код:

```
pcap_t* traffic;
if ((traffic = pcap_open_offline(path, nullptr)) == nullptr)
{
        std::cout << "Error open traffic file! \n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
readDnsPacket(traffic);
```

Функция readDnsPacket:

```
inline void readDnsPacket(pcap_t* traffic)
{
    struct bpf_program fp;
    char *str = "udp and src port 53"; //filter for dns-response
    pcap_compile(traffic, &fp, str, 1, 0xffffff);
    pcap_setfilter(traffic, &fp);
    pcap_loop(traffic, 0, PacketHandler, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Не знаю, что такое pcap, но возможно вам просто нужно сделать копию данных по этому указателю в какой-нибудь другой буфер? std::copy, memcpy

Comment: Вряд ли здесь поможет memcpy. pcap_t - это алиас для `struct pcap`, а описание этой структуры я не нашёл. Вы, конечно, можете скопировать эту структуру через memcpy, но в ней скорее всего будут ещё разные указатели на другие структуры или массивы. Придётся копировать их все. Поэтому, не имея опыта работы с pcap, могу предложить лишь заново прочитать файл.

Comment: Опять же совсем не разбираюсь в особенностях pcap, но, может быть, вот эта ссылка вам немного поможет, тут вроде пытаются решить похожую проблему http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499206/memcpy-and-memory-management-with-pcap

Comment: Там пакеты копируют, на них указатели хотя бы u_char. Да и узнать размер пакета возможно по header, а тут как узнать, какое количество байт нужно копировать?..